# Effective power text message

Tags: iphone

my brother sent my friend an effective power message and his phone turned off completely. His phone doesn't work at all and supposedly it's on "boot loop" where the screen only shows the apple logo and it is staying like that. Any ideas on how to fix his phone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try hard rebooting the device. Hold the power button and the home button for 10 seconds or longer. If you phone does not have certain buttons ie force touch home button/ iphone X please use [this](https://www.macobserver.com/tips/quick-tip/iphone-x-hard-reboot-the-iphone-x/) article to figure out how to hard reboot your phone.

If you cannot break out of the boot loop and you cannot hard restart your phone, take it in to an apple specialist and if it is an issue with the Operating system they will certainly help you fix it.